# Make endpoint that returns a list of strings using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have this Artist model:

```py
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #songs = models.ManyToManyField('Song', related_name='artists')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

I want to make a api endpoint that returns all the Artists row names as a list of string like for example: ["50 Cent", "Eminem", "Snoop Dogg", ...] . i have created this `artists/names/` url in my urls.py:

```py
path('artists/names/', views.artist_names, name='artist_names'),
```

I have tried two ways already:

1. Using a python list:

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def artist_names(request):
    artists = Artist.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
    artist_names_list = list(artists)
    return Response(artist_names_list)
```

2. Using ListSerializer in my serializers.py:

```py
class ArtistNameSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.ListSerializer(child=serializers.CharField())
```

and in my views.py i created the artist_names method:

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def artist_names(request):
    artists = Artist.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
    serializer = ArtistNameSerializer(artists, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

From both of them when i go to the endpoint i get:

```
GET /api/artists/names/
HTTP 404 Not Found
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

Can someone help? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your URL `/api/artists/names/` could not be found. Make sure you use the correct URL.

Comment: @Sulejman Hoxha let me know if the solution below works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine the issue you would have with your method (1) is that without 'serializing' first, your Python list is not valid JSON, so won't be handled correctly by DRF.

Your method (2) is on the right track, but you are using a `serializers.ListSerializer` inside your 'Serializer' class, where you should be putting a `serializers.ListField`. You also don't need `many=True` in your view once this is corrected.

The below is how I got your code working:

---

**serializers.py**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Artist


class ArtistSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    artists = Artist.objects.all()
    names = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.CharField(max_length=100),
        default=artists
    )
```

**views.py**

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Artist
from .serializers import ArtistSerializer


@api_view(['GET'])
def artist_names(request):
    artists = Artist.objects.all()
    serializer = ArtistSerializer(artists)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py *(in app)***

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('artists/names/', views.artist_names, name='artist_names'),
]
```

---

The **models.py** file is identical to yours, and the project-level urls.py file features the line `path('', include('app.urls')),`, so just make sure to include that and change *app* to whatever name your app is.

The output this gave me is below:

[image: Picture of API Output]

---

Hopefully if you make the above adjustments (looks like they are mostly just the minor changes to your serializers and views files I outlined above) then you'll see the same output!

Comment: Thanks for your reply :D. I tried your code and it did not work. Then a stupid thought came in my mind "Just try a different path endpoint" and i did, i changed from `artists/names/` to `artist-names/` and now it works and i am even more confused. i tried my previous solutions and the first one with python list worked aswell. why did the previous endpoint give me errors i have no clue since i am using other similar endpoints that work. Either way thanks for your help, now i have two solutions :D.

Comment: I now understand why it was not working, i am stupid :( . I am using DefaultRouter with my Artist model and i have registered it like this: 
```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'songs', views.SongViewSet)
```
so after the `artists/` it expects a number for the Artist id after it,  so the previous endpoint `artists/names/` with whatever code it would not work.

Comment: i meant `router.register(r'artists', views.ArtistViewSet)`

Comment: Yes, using ViewSets + DefaultRouter would be the default and definitely easiest way to set up an API. Your original code was the vanilla api_view though, which may have been the root cause of your difficulty if you were following instructions for ViewSets! Glad it's all working now :D

Comment: This site, Classy DRF, is a fantastic resource for understanding how the different DRF components all fit together: https://www.cdrf.co/ 
Would definitely recommend (alongside Classy Forms and Classy Views if you use them elsewhere in your Django projects)